# Razor radio button don't work (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to create an ASP.NET MVC application for my completion of course work, using .NET / C# and Razor.

I want to create an application that has a quiz so I get the questions and their alternatives using SQL, sent to a view through `TempData` and use two for to go through these structures, like this after the quiz be filled in I need to send the information to a controller.

Basically what I need is to fill the `AlternativaEscolhida` with true or false and send it to a controller

Github : https://github.com/joaogqueiroz/PoupaAiMVC

Controller

```
public IActionResult ValidaRespostas(AvaliacaoModel model)
{
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            TempData["Messege"] = "Error" + e.Message;
        }

        return View();
}
```

View Questionario

```
@using PoupaAiMVC.Data.Entities
@model PoupaAiMVC.Models.Questionario.AvaliacaoModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Avaliacao";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/Layout.cshtml";
    var questoes = TempData["Questoes"] as List<PoupaAiMVC.Data.Entities.Questao>;
    var alternativas = TempData["Alternativas"] as List<PoupaAiMVC.Data.Entities.Alternativa>;
}

<br />

@for (int i = 0; i < questoes.Count(); i++)
{

    <div class="accordion accordion-flush" id="accordionFlush_@i">
        <div class="accordion-item">
            <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-heading_@i">
                <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapse_@i" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapse_@i">
                    @{int contador = i + 1;}
                    Questão @contador
                </button>
            </h2>
            <div id="flush-collapse_@i" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-heading_@i" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
                <div class="accordion-body">@questoes[i].Enunciado</div>
                <br />
                <br />



                @for (int j = 0; j < alternativas.Count(); j++)
                {
                    @if (alternativas[j].Id_Questao == questoes[i].IdQuestao)
                    {
                        <div>
                                @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Alternativas[j].IdAlternativa, alternativas[j].AlternativaEscolhida)
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Questoes[i].Enunciado)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.Alternativas[j].correta)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.Alternativas[j].IdAlternativa)</div>
                            }

                            }
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }

                    <div class="d-grid">
                        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="@Url.Action("ValidaRespostas","Questionario")">Finalizar</a>
                    </div>
```

Model AvaliacaoModel

```
using PoupaAiMVC.Data.Entities;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PoupaAiMVC.Models.Questionario
{
    public class AvaliacaoModel
    {
        [Required]
        public List<Questao> Questoes { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public List<Alternativa> Alternativas { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Entity `Questao`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PoupaAiMVC.Data.Entities
{
    public class Questao
    {
        public int IdQuestao { get; set; }
        public string Enunciado { get; set; }
        public int Imagem { get; set; }
        public TipoQuestao TipoQuestao { get; set; }
        public Nivel Nivel { get; set; }
        public List<Alternativa> Alternativas { get; set; }

        public static implicit operator List<object>(Questao v)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Entity `Alternativas`:

```
public class Alternativa
{
    public int IdAlternativa { get; set; }
    public string alternativa { get; set; }
    public string correta { get; set; }
    public int Id_Questao { get; set; }
    public bool AlternativaEscolhida { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Adjusted like @marc_s asked for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my app . i used this source and work it

```
 public class ReportFormReportFormAccessModel
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public bool isRole { get; set; }
        public bool Selected { get; set; }
    }
```

```
 <div class="panel-body">
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.ListOfRole.Count; i++)
                {
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div>
                            <label>
                                @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => Model.ListOfRole[i].Selected, new { @class = "GroupClass" }) @Model.ListOfRole[i].Text
                            </label>
                            @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.ListOfRole[i].Value)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.ListOfRole[i].Text)


                        </div>
                    </div>
                }

            </div>
```

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public JsonResult MVReportForm(ReportForm model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
             }
            return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```